# How do you translate the rows of French and Arabic text in the columns into English?

Tags: python-3.x, translation

I want to translate a dataframe column that's in French and Arabic:

```
0                                       Chef de projet
                                                   ...
6                                           professeur
7                                       Chef de projet
8                                           مدير  شركة
```

I tried:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
df['new_professionactuelle']= df['new_professionactuelle'].apply(translator.translate)
```

But obtained

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-90b46ab0043a> in <module>
      1 from googletrans import Translator
      2 translator = Translator()
----> 3 df['new_professionactuelle']= df['new_professionactuelle'].apply(translator.translate)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src)
    170 
    171         origin = text
--> 172         data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
    173 
    174         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src)
     73             text = text.decode('utf-8')
     74 
---> 75         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     76         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     77                                     token=token)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    199     def do(self, text):
    200         self._update()
--> 201         tk = self.acquire(text)
    202         return tk

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in acquire(self, text)
    144         a = []
    145         # Convert text to ints
--> 146         for i in text:
    147             val = ord(i)
    148             if val < 0x10000:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I tried to get the rows that might be `NoneType`:

```
df['new_professionactuelle'][type(df['new_professionactuelle']) == "NoneType"]
```

But got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-215-f2597906f267> in <module>
----> 1 df['new_professionactuelle'][type(df['new_professionactuelle']) == "NoneType"]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to convert all text into english text.

```
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

def toenglish(x):
    print(x)
    result = translator.translate(x, dest='en')
    return result.text

df['new_professionactuelle'] = list(map(toenglish, df['text']))
```